# How to find duplicate images

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2014-localdb

Using the below table I need to find duplicate image records. The query is used to find records but not accurate results coming. After fetching duplicate image records then we want to fetch only those records who have FM_NAME_EN, LASTNAME_EN, RLN_TYPE, RLN_FM_NM_EN, RLN_L_NM_EN,GENDER,AGE and PHOTO are same.
Table used have column like as below

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ERoll](
    [AC_NO] [int] NULL,
    [PART_NO] [int] NULL,
    [SLNOINPART] [int] NULL,
    [FM_NAME_EN] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [LASTNAME_EN] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [RLN_TYPE] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [RLN_FM_NM_EN] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [RLN_L_NM_EN] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [EPIC_NO] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [GENDER] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [AGE] [int] NULL,
    [PHOTO] [image] NULL
);
```

In the above table some records with duplicate images. So **how we can find duplicate image records**?

**Only 50% records are coming correctly** through below query:

```
SELECT e.AC_NO, e.PART_NO, e.SLNOINPART, e.FM_NAME_EN, e.LASTNAME_EN, 
    e.RLN_FM_NM_EN, e.RLN_L_NM_EN, e.RLN_TYPE, e.GENDER, e.AGE
FROM S21_EROLL_MANAGEMENT_PROD.dbo.ERoll e
JOIN (
    select FM_NAME_EN, LASTNAME_EN, RLN_FM_NM_EN, RLN_L_NM_EN, RLN_TYPE, GENDER, AGE, hashbytes('md5', cast([PHOTO] as varbinary)) PHOTO ,count(*) PHOTO_COUNT
    from S21_EROLL_MANAGEMENT_PROD.dbo.ERoll
    group by FM_NAME_EN, LASTNAME_EN, RLN_FM_NM_EN, RLN_L_NM_EN, RLN_TYPE, GENDER, AGE, hashbytes('md5', cast([PHOTO] as varbinary)) 
    having count(*) > 1
) d ON e.FM_NAME_EN = d.FM_NAME_EN and e.LASTNAME_EN = d.LASTNAME_EN and e.RLN_FM_NM_EN=d.RLN_FM_NM_EN 
    and e.RLN_L_NM_EN = d.RLN_L_NM_EN and e.RLN_TYPE = d.RLN_TYPE and e.GENDER = d.GENDER and e.AGE = d.AGE
order by AC_NO, PART_NO, SLNOINPART
```

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT().

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Use `varbinary(max)`

Answer (score 1):

Uing GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT() :

```
select hashbytes('md5', cast([imagecolumn] as varbinary(max))),count(*)
from yourtable
group by hashbytes('md5', cast([imagecolumn] as varbinary(max)))
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: It seems like I have already used this as inner query, but actual problem you didn't understand . for photo we are using image data type. so in that case you can not fetch data using your query. We need to cast image into varbinary for finding duplicate images.

Comment: Again your query is wrong, If you are using photo field in group by then its not showing duplicate images. You have put group by on photo, which is wrong.

Comment: `varbinary(max)` I think is the point here

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try find duplicate photos like this

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', cast(photo as varbinary(max))) from dbo.ERoll
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*
             count(*) over (partition by FM_NAME_EN, LASTNAME_EN, RLN_FM_NM_EN, RLN_L_NM_EN, RLN_TYPE, GENDER, AGE, hashbytes('md5', cast([PHOTO] as varbinary))) as cnt
      from S21_EROLL_MANAGEMENT_PROD.dbo.ERoll e
     ) e
where cnt > 1;
```